# Adding one value to all column in the database

Tags: c#, sql

I have here a problem on how to add one value in all columns of a database.

Here's what it looks like

[image: Windows Form showing SQL Table]

I use SQL query to add the other values and here's the code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    LeaveDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter employees = new LeaveDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter();
    employees.InsertEmployee(this.txtID.Text.Trim(),
        this.txtName.Text.Trim(),
        this.txtLeaveCredits.Text.Trim());

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'leaveDatabaseDataSet.Employees' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.leaveDatabaseDataSet.Employees);

}
```

I haven't put some codes on the "Add Monthly Leave Credits" button because i don't have any idea on how to do this assignment.

Comment: I am not sure about how you use SQL because you don't show it in your pasted code. You can use "UPDATE TableName SET LeaveCredits = LeaveCredits + 2.5" SQL statement to do this in SQL.

Comment: i use an insert code on inserting the values "INSERT INTO Employees(ID, Name, LeaveCredits) VALUES(@ID,@Name, @LeaveCredits)" but i don't have any idea on how to add a single value in all columns of a database.

Comment: " add one value in all columns " - your post/title talks about "all columns" but it looks like you have much more sensible request to update all values in single column... Please clarify which one you are looking for.

Comment: @Emman Ok, check the answer. It should be correct.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm sorry man.. I'm not very good in english maybe that's why I don't have any sense on making my post/title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about how you use SQL because you don't show it in your pasted code.

You need to implement LeaveDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter.AddMontlyLeaveCredits() method using the following SQL statement.

```
UPDATE Employees SET LeaveCredits = LeaveCredits + @mc
```

And add @mc as a parameter from your TextBox.